# Is lotus root davar charif?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

[Lotus root](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelumbo_nucifera#Uses) is a common ingredient in Asian cooking, and it has a distinctive shape. Is lotus root a davar charif for kashrut purposes?

Comment: From the Wikipedia article it seems they are often pickled - thus raw they would not be particularly sharp. How sharp are they?

Comment: Oh! So THAT's what this stuff is! I've seen this in good Chinese vegetarian food, and I thought it was what they call "bitter mellon". Thanks for the link to the pics. This stuff is not sharp at all when it is cooked plain. I didn't know that they pickle this stuff.